# Sending a download progres via Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

If I use the `helperFile` I can only send `download complete` back to the Component by returning the Promise. But **how can i send the progress variable back to the Component** to use it later to implement a downloading progress bar.

I'm also able to do it if I put all the code inside the Component, but that's horrible.

**Helper File**

```
const request = require('request');

class helperFile{
    static downloadFile(file_url, targetPath, callback) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let received_bytes = 0;
            let total_bytes = 0;

            let req = request({
                method: 'GET',
                uri: file_url
            });

            let out = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
            req.pipe(out);

            req.on('response', function (data) {
                total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
            });

            req.on('data', function (chunk) {
                received_bytes += chunk.length;
                let progress = (received_bytes * 100) / total_bytes;

                return progress
            });

            req.on('end', function () {
                resolve(true)
                console.log("File succesfully downloaded");
            });
        })
    }
}
```

**React Component**

```
import helperFile from '../actions/download'

   handleDownloadFile() {
       helperFile.downloadFile('https:...', 'path' )
       .then((response) => console.log(response))
   }
```

> The expected output should be 1,2,3,...100, and when finished `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback that will update the state of the React Component.

```
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    received_bytes += chunk.length;

    const progress = (received_bytes * 100) / total_bytes;

    callback(progress);
});
```

In your React Component

```
handleDownloadFile() {
   helperFile.downloadFile('https:...', 'path', this.updateProgress)
   .then((response) => console.log(response))
}

updateProgress(progress) {
    this.setState({progress});
}
```

Comment: Because i need to use it in the Component to implement a download progress bar.